# Iterating over timestamp in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The portion of pandas dataframe is given below:

```
 timestamp             quantity price Dates     Time     store_price
 2016-07-01 09:15:55    750 1237.50 2016-07-01  09:15:55    nan
 2016-07-01 09:16:01    750 1237.35 2016-07-01  09:16:01    nan     
 2016-07-01 09:16:46    750 1238.15 2016-07-01  09:16:46    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:16:46    750 1238.00 2016-07-01  09:16:46    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:18:12    750 1239.70 2016-07-01  09:18:12    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:19:05    1500 1237.45 2016-07-01 09:19:05    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:19:58    750 1234.70 2016-07-01  09:19:58    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:20:02    750 1234.95 2016-07-01  09:20:02    nan
 2016-07-01 09:20:04    750 1234.00 2016-07-01  09:20:04    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:20:28    750 1237.25 2016-07-01  09:20:28    nan
 2016-07-01 09:21:18    750 1238.30 2016-07-01  09:21:18    nan
 2016-07-01 09:22:29    750 1237.55 2016-07-01  09:22:29    nan
 2016-07-01 09:22:51    750 1237.50 2016-07-01  09:22:51    nan
 2016-07-01 09:23:25    750 1237.05 2016-07-01  09:23:25    nan
 2016-07-01 09:23:28    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:23:28    nan
 2016-07-01 09:24:19    750 1237.05 2016-07-01  09:24:19    nan
 2016-07-01 09:24:19    2250 1237.00 2016-07-01 09:24:19    nan
 2016-07-01 09:24:25    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:24:25    nan
 2016-07-01 09:25:23    750 1236.05 2016-07-01  09:25:23    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:26:10    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:26:10    nan
 2016-07-01 09:26:18    750 1237.90 2016-07-01  09:26:18    nan
 2016-07-01 09:26:25    750 1237.05 2016-07-01  09:26:25    nan     
 2016-07-01 09:27:54    750 1233.50 2016-07-01  09:27:54    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:28:25    750 1233.85 2016-07-01  09:28:25    nan
 2016-07-01 09:29:17    750 1234.85 2016-07-01  09:29:17    nan
 2016-07-01 09:29:36    750 1235.45 2016-07-01  09:29:36    nan
 2016-07-01 09:29:54    750 1235.00 2016-07-01  09:29:54    nan
 2016-07-01 09:30:06    750 1236.65 2016-07-01  09:30:06    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:30:36    750 1236.60 2016-07-01  09:30:36    nan
 2016-07-01 09:31:01    750 1236.60 2016-07-01  09:31:01    nan
 2016-07-01 09:31:09    750 1236.70 2016-07-01  09:31:09    nan
 2016-07-01 09:31:15    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:31:15    nan
```

I want to get dataframe like below, i.e, to store `price` value in a different column `store_price` for rows in the time range 09.20.00 to 09.30.00:

```
 timestamp             quantity price Dates     Time     store_price
 2016-07-01 09:15:55    750 1237.50 2016-07-01  09:15:55    nan
 2016-07-01 09:16:01    750 1237.35 2016-07-01  09:16:01    nan     
 2016-07-01 09:16:46    750 1238.15 2016-07-01  09:16:46    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:16:46    750 1238.00 2016-07-01  09:16:46    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:18:12    750 1239.70 2016-07-01  09:18:12    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:19:05    1500 1237.45 2016-07-01 09:19:05    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:19:58    750 1234.70 2016-07-01  09:19:58    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:20:02    750 1234.95 2016-07-01  09:20:02    1234.95
 2016-07-01 09:20:04    750 1234.00 2016-07-01  09:20:04    1234.00     
 2016-07-01 09:20:28    750 1237.25 2016-07-01  09:20:28    1237.25
 2016-07-01 09:21:18    750 1238.30 2016-07-01  09:21:18    1238.30
 2016-07-01 09:22:29    750 1237.55 2016-07-01  09:22:29    1237.55
 2016-07-01 09:22:51    750 1237.50 2016-07-01  09:22:51    1237.50 
 2016-07-01 09:23:25    750 1237.05 2016-07-01  09:23:25    1237.05
 2016-07-01 09:23:28    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:23:28    1237.00
 2016-07-01 09:24:19    750 1237.05 2016-07-01  09:24:19    1237.05
 2016-07-01 09:24:19    2250 1237.00 2016-07-01 09:24:19    1237.00
 2016-07-01 09:24:25    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:24:25    1237.00
 2016-07-01 09:25:23    750 1236.05 2016-07-01  09:25:23    1236.05 
 2016-07-01 09:26:10    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:26:10    1237.00
 2016-07-01 09:26:18    750 1237.90 2016-07-01  09:26:18    1237.90
 2016-07-01 09:26:25    750 1237.05 2016-07-01  09:26:25    1237.05     
 2016-07-01 09:27:54    750 1233.50 2016-07-01  09:27:54    1233.50 
 2016-07-01 09:28:25    750 1233.85 2016-07-01  09:28:25    1233.85
 2016-07-01 09:29:17    750 1234.85 2016-07-01  09:29:17    1234.85
 2016-07-01 09:29:36    750 1235.45 2016-07-01  09:29:36    1235.45
 2016-07-01 09:29:54    750 1235.00 2016-07-01  09:29:54    1235.00
 2016-07-01 09:30:06    750 1236.65 2016-07-01  09:30:06    nan 
 2016-07-01 09:30:36    750 1236.60 2016-07-01  09:30:36    nan
 2016-07-01 09:31:01    750 1236.60 2016-07-01  09:31:01    nan
 2016-07-01 09:31:09    750 1236.70 2016-07-01  09:31:09    nan
 2016-07-01 09:31:15    750 1237.00 2016-07-01  09:31:15    nan
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! You have provided an example of the dataframe. That's great! You mention about storing data in a different column as well as saving data from a time interval. Can you try to provide another dataframe example of showing the expected series or dataframe? Thanks!

Comment: timestamp                   quantity  price Dates        Time       store_price
2016-07-01 09:15:09 750 1231.95 2016-07-01 09:15:09     nan
2016-07-01 09:15:28 750 1242.00 2016-07-01 09:15:28     nan
2016-07-01 09:16:26 750 1237.30 2016-07-01 09:16:26     nan
2016-07-01 09:18:48 750 1239.00 2016-07-01 09:18:48     nan
2016-07-01 09:20:02 750 1234.95 2016-07-01 09:20:02    1234.95 
2016-07-01 09:20:04 750 1234.00 2016-07-01 09:20:04   1234.00
I was tryingfor (datetime.time(9, 15, 0)<timeindex(df[i,4])<datetime.time(9, 30, 0))
    df[i,5]=df[i,2]
        i=i+1

Comment: Hi again. The comment area isn't suitable for data formatting. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53308031/edit) your question and put the expected data up there instead?

Comment: I created numpy array ,then tried a 'for' loop,                                                  for (datetime.time(9, 15, 0)<timeindex(df[i,4])<datetime.time(9, 30, 0))
    df[i,5]=df[i,2]
        i=i+1

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']) # Only if needed
condition = (df['timestamp'].dt.hour == 9) & (df['timestamp'].dt.minute >= 20) & (df['timestamp'].dt.minute <= 30)
df.loc[condition, "store_price"] = df.loc[condition, "price"]
```

#### Explanation

First, make sure `timestamp` column is of type `datetime`:

```
df['timestamp'].dtypes
```

If it returns `dtype('O')`, you need to cast it to datetime using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), as below:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['timestamp'].dtypes
>>> dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Now you can access the hour and the minute of the column with the [.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor and write a mask as below:

```
condition = (df['timestamp'].dt.hour == 9) & (df['timestamp'].dt.minute >= 20) & (df['timestamp'].dt.minute <= 30)
```

Finally, you can override the `store_price` column with `price` only for the rows that match the condition using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[condition, "store_price"] = df.loc[condition, "price"]
```

Obtaining the results you want.